# Adding Secondary Site Collection Administrator SharePoint 2016 PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm trying to add a user as a 'Secondary Site Collection Administrator' using the following PowerShell script :

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | %{Set-SPSite $_ -SecondaryOwnerAlias "i:0#.w|contoso\adminuser"}
```

when it runs it says the user cannot be found. I've tried 'i:0#.w|contoso\adminuser' and 'contoso\adminuser' and still the same. This fails to add the user as a secondary collection administrator. I have noticed one thing with this script. These are the steps :

1. Add 'contoso\adminuser' as a secondary collection administrator through the UI. click ok. redirects back to the central admin page.
2. Go back in and remove 'contoso\adminuser' from the secondary collection owner and click ok redirects back.

If I run the script again it works, it adds the user as a 'secondary collection administrator'

Do I need to add this user to the site first as a limited user or something else?

I just want to add the user to all site and sub collections.

**EDIT**
'contoso\adminuser' has been imported from Active Directory. If I create a new site and try and run the script again it will not add the user to the site collection. To get the script to work I have to add and the remove the user through the UI. I then run the script and it adds the user as a secondary collection owner but still gives me the error user does not exist.

I have come across cases in SharePoint Online. I think the user needs to be added some how as a Limited Access.

Another test I have just done is by sharing a folder in the team site with read permissions. Once I did that and ran the script it added the user as a secondary collection administrator

[image]

Comment: No issues here using your code. On the Jan 2017 PU.

Comment: Does it work first time if you create a new site?

Comment: @Trevor, could you please try with a user who is not in sharepoint...brand new user...i think i got this error

Comment: It works just fine with a new user. Created one in AD, then ran through this code, including on a site that had no secondary user previously.

Comment: I've just added more information and another test

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user may not exist in that site collection yet. Try using EnsureUser to ensure the user exists, then add as Secondary Site Collection Administrator.

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | % {
    $_.RootWeb.EnsureUser("contoso\adminuser")
    Set-SPSite $_ -SecondaryOwnerAlias "contoso\adminuser"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I get the user to exist in a new site collection? Can I add the user? Thanks

Comment: The EnsureUser method will automatically add the user if necessary.

Comment: This isn't necessary to do. Setting the SCA brings in the user from AD when you set it.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be adding it and so not adding it as a secondary collection admin. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: The above works on the root url ie http:://sp2016/ but not on any subsites http://sp2016/sites/new site

Comment: This is an interesting issue you're experiencing. The above PowerShell will work on all Site Collections by adding the user to the root Web of each, which shouldn't even be necessary if the user is in AD. Can you check the ULS logs for a more precise error occurring when the script is ran?

Comment: I'll check the logs and update question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ornerywalrus I've taken a look at the log located here C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS and nothing stands out when running the script at the same time. Is it how I've setup sharepoint? I imported users from AD and the sharepoint userids are contoso\username